# AVCaptionSession and AVAudioSession cause AVPlayer pause to play

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I found, if stop running `AVCaptureSession`, and change `AVAudioSession` category right after -AVPlayer:play function may cause player pause to play.

[image]

[Code](https://github.com/bottotl/testPlayer)

Her are a [video](http://jft0m-1254413962.cossh.myqcloud.com/IMG_1407.m4v) show this bug

It should switch between `Capture` and `Player`, one at once. But some time, stop capture will cause player stop play.

I found this code run as I expected in iOS 9.3, but in iOS 11.3 this bug always show.

Comment: I think I have to play video after camera started